# csv file- find who has min and max

Tags: python, pandas

[image: input data]

As shown above I need to get who has the max and min balance using python program. Tried different ways. But not able to get who (name). Need help

Adding my code

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:data1.csv')
#FINDING MAX AND MIN
p=df['balance'].max()
q=df['balance'].min()
print(q)
print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the entire row(s) for the records matching the minimum and maximum balance, then the following should do the trick:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:data1.csv')

max_balance_rows = df[df['balance']==df['balance'].max()]
min_balance_rows = df[df['balance']==df['balance'].min()]
```

Comment: This code really helped. Now I can add details to the print option to show the details I need to print. Thanks again

Comment: One more question. Is there a way to only add first name, last name and balance

Comment: @heart1possible You can select specific columns : `df = df[['name', 'last', 'balance']]`

Comment: Thanks for answering. How can I print this way. minimum balance- terry smith - 1000